# How to remove the old site from Google Search and reset Google Search Console after developing a new website

Tags: google-search, url-parameters

I have made a web app in Meteor  to replace an old site that was made using PHP.

The site is up and it's working.  The problem I'm having with it is SEO and Google search.   I know this is not easy with any NodeJS app, but aside from this the real problem is  when I search for it on Google, I receive the links for the old site that aren't  valid.

How can I reset Google Search Console (parameter url, index,...)?

Comment: Don't you mean you want to _reset_ "Google Search"? Google Search _Console_ (GSC) isn't something you "reset" - it's a tool for reporting on and managing (to some extent) the Google search results.

Comment: You need to 301-redirect the old URLs to the new. Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99791/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-seo-friendly

Comment: Also, I would like to mention that search engines are not real-time and are in fact, notoriously slow. Think about it, the web is so HUGE that it is impossible to be highly responsive.

Answer (score 3):

Primarily I see 2 core issues you are facing,

*1. I receive the links for the old site that aren't valid.*

There are couple of ways you can go past this. Assuming, you have limited number of pages, performing (permanent) redirections using nginx/apache using pattern patching (or exact url). Other could be, handle the links at application level using JavaScript.

*2. How can I reset Google Search Console (parameter url, index,...)?*

Two points, first, there is no "one click remove all links" method for Google Search. Second, through Google Search Console is a way for you to provide indication to Google about your website. The more specific you are , the better it is. In you case, if you have revamped your web app and old links aren't valid then point the old links to new ones through permanent redirects. If they aren't valid anymore, throw 404 errors. Over a period of time, the errors will start popping up in console, for you to track and make amends are required.

Lastly, by "reset" if you meant start fresh then one possible, crude way could be to delete the property and create new one.

Comment: The old site is all developed with parameters url, so all urls are in the form: www.site.com/?do=foo&a=bar&so=on, cable this logic into my app it's awful. I don't think simply delete property will reset google search, because the site wasn't connected to google search console.